# URL link SEO and security using Laravel

Tags: php, security, url, laravel

I'm trying to figure out what the best way to do this is.

I have a part on my website where people can search for a particular card based on multiple different factors. Like the name of the card, color, cost, etc. When the user types in the criteria, I send the information via ajax GET. So the url looks something like this:

```
http://sitename.dev/search?query=asdf&color=red&etc=
```

The good thing is, the above provides a url so the user can easily copy paste and share the results with friends. The not so good part is, it's not so good for search engine optimization.

First question: How do I make these type of links good for SEO and is this secure? It seems like it would be easy to inject code?

Second question:

After getting the corresponding input from the user, I have the following in my SearchController to deal with the input:

```
public function postSearchResults() {
        $searchStr = Input::get('query');
        $color = Input::get('color');
        $etc = Input::get('etc');

        $query = DB::connection('mysql')->table('cards')
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$searchStr.'%')
            ->where('color', 'LIKE', '%'.$color.'%')
            ->where('etc', 'LIKE', '%'.$etc.'%')
            ->get();

        return parent::ajaxView('results', compact('query'));
}
```

Is the above secure or is there something I should do in addition to make it secure?

Answer (score 1):

**First question: How do I make these type of links good for SEO**

I can't confidently say that it's *bad* in its current state as I'm not too clued up on SEO, see this link for some more info https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15393/is-a-url-with-a-query-string-better-or-worse-for-seo-then-one-without-one

I'm guessing if you wanted to make it somewhat more human and or seo friendly you can set your route up as so:

```
Route::get('{search}/{color}/{etc}', [
  'uses' => 'SearchController@postSearchResults'
]);
```

Then you'd need to add some parameters to the controller:

```
public function postSearchResults($search, $color, $etc) {

        $query = DB::connection('mysql')->table('cards')
            ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->where('color', 'LIKE', '%'.$color.'%')
            ->where('etc', 'LIKE', '%'.$etc.'%')
            ->get();

        return parent::ajaxView('results', compact('query'));
}
```

*Note: you may want to change your method name to `getSearchResults()` instead of `postSearchResults()`, as you are using the GET ajax method when calling the route, right?*

**and is this secure? It seems like it would be easy to inject code?**

From the Laravel Documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#introduction

> Note: The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding throughout
>   to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no
>   need to clean strings being passed as bindings.

**Second question: After getting the corresponding input from the user, I have the following in my SearchController to deal with the input:**

... your code

**Is the above secure or is there something I should do in addition to make it secure?**

I'd like to think it's pretty secure based on what is aforementioned regarding how the query builder works.

Finally, don't consider this a complete answer. I'd definitely do some more digging around or maybe someone with more knowledge will come and post another answer! All the best!